# Brakes or suspension i really need some help

Tags: honda

When I push down on my brakes my steering wheel turns a little to the left and when I release  I hear and feel a single pop, any idea on what it may be? I have just recently got my brakes done.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please do yourself a favor and take it back to them. If it wasn't doing it before the brake job, it shouldn't be doing it after. They need to fix their work.

Comment: How long is « just recently »? Last week, last month or last year?